# "Done" or "Go" for password field in signup / login form?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikeyboard

Should "Done" or "Go" be written on the keyboard return button when entering the password in a signup or login form?

I've seen it both ways. Is there a best practice or design guideline?

Answer (score 0):

The way I decide what to put in the return key of the keyboard depends upon the position of each text field in the form and the action it should perform.

E.g: If I have a login form with two fields, i.e username and password, I will set 'Next' for username field and will move the focus towards password field on pressing the 'Next'. For password field I will set the return key to 'Send' and upon pressing the send, will call the login routine.

So, for any field in the middle of the form, I set it to display 'Next' and move the focus to the next field upon pressing and for the last field, I set it to 'Send' and actually perform the task upon pressing the send.